# Need help writing and reading XML file in C#

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

Idea - List of vertices(Key, X, Y, Priority to store).

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <Vertices>
    <Vertex Key="0" X="149" Y="209" Priority="7" />
    <Vertex Key="1" X="278" Y="128" Priority="7" />
   </Vertex>
```

Is this valid XML? It keeps saying me that root element is missing, when i try to open it... If so, can someone provide a valid c# XDocument code to open this file ?

Comment: Did you paste it in wrong? your closing tag shows as `</Vertex>` not `</Vertices>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not valid XML - your closing element has the wrong name - this would be valid:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Vertices>
  <Vertex Key="0" X="149" Y="209" Priority="7" />
  <Vertex Key="1" X="278" Y="128" Priority="7" />
</Vertices>
```

Also make sure that if you are loading an XML *file* you use `XDocument.Load` and not `XDocument.Parse`.

Comment: I was using memorystream to extract file from zip into memory. memorystream.Position = 0; Solved my errors.

Answer (score 1):

You are opening `<Vertices>` but closing `</Vertex>`. Need to change that last closing tag to `</Vertices>`

Side note:

If you load an XML file into Visual Studio it will tell you if it is invalid XML and why. For this example it gave the errors:

```
Error   1   Tag was not closed. XMLFile1.xml    Line 2  Column 5
Error   2   Expecting end tag </Vertices>.  XMLFile1.xml    Line 5  Column 6
```

If you do not own Visual Studio, you can download the Express version for free and get the same functionality.

Comment: sorry, typo.. actually it is like that. That means, my xml is correct, but my loader is failing. this cuts my problem in half :)